# How to configure Notepad++ to backspace unindent

Tags: editor, notepad++

I can't seem to find where to configure this option. Backspace unindent only works when using hard tabs, but should'nt this work since it works on other Scintilla based editors (eg Scite)?

Answer (score 12):

The solution I've found, which works exactly like Scite's solution does, is a little plugin from Virtual Roadside named [npp_tabs](http://www.virtualroadside.com/blog/index.php/2012/12/03/notepad-plugin-to-enable-unindent-on-backspace-key/). Highly recommended - after three separate attempts, it's the only thing I found that worked how I wanted.

Comment: A bug was filed 1 week ago, it seems: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1817 - unsure if duplicate, but that was the top result referencing a bug in my search.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setting > Shortcut Mapper then click the "Scintilla Commands" tab.  Line 11 (on my version) is where you set the shortcut key for "SCI_BACKTAB".  Highlight it and press "Modify" and you can set it to whatever you would like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work acceptably - it would let me unbackspace, but I could no longer delete lines with the backspace key.

Answer (score 2):

npp_tabs seems not working anymore.

Use ExtSettings, which is available through PluginsAdmin.

Website:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/extsettings/